# jquery validate message container

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to show error messages after input (what is working fine:

[image: https://prnt.sc/e6YJJ-mvWO2O]

and after submit in message container which is default in form:

[image: https://prnt.sc/rn6Tjn95t68b]

```
  $("#form_name").validate({
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        $(element.form).find("input[id=" + element.id + "]")
            .addClass(errorClass);
        $(element.form).find("input[id=" + element.id + "]").siblings(".successClass").hide();

    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        $(element.form).find("input[id=" + element.id + "]")
            .removeClass(errorClass);
        $(element.form).find("input[id=" + element.id + "]").siblings(".successClass").fadeIn();
    },

    rules: {
        billing_phone: {
            minlength: 9,
            number: true
        },

    },


});


 $("#submit").on("click", function () {

    $("#form_name").validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.clone().insertAfter(".message-container");

        }
    });

});
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for help, A

Comment: Put the HTML of the form into the question so we can help you.  Do not put `.validate()` inside of a click handler since the plugin already captures the click/submit event.   The `.validate()` method cannot be called twice on the same form.   Put the `errorPlacement` option inside the first one with the other options.   Just use `.validate()` to initialize the plugin on the form.

Comment: Hello, I understand about click but didn't know how achieve both: message in container and message after label. In meantime I create custom validation with no problems:) Thanks for help